# WebView native crash: libwebviewchromium.so "Operation not permitted" - ILL_ILLOPC

Tags: android, crash, android-webview, samsung-mobile

I'm seeing a lot of crash reports similar to the crash below, and I'm at a loss for how to diagnose the issue.

Crash heading in Google Developer Console:

> Native crash at
>   /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
>   in
>   /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so,
>   26743 failed: Operation not permitted

Crash detail:

```
Build fingerprint: 
'samsung/trltetmo/trltetmo:5.1.1/LMY47X/N910TUVU2DOK2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '12' ABI: 'arm' pid: 26743, tid: 29439, name:
DedicatedWorker  >>> package-removed <<< signal
4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 0xa3f94e26
    r0 00000053  r1 64499bb1  r2 64499bb1  r3 00000001
    r4 66a99000  r5 a4b2fb94  r6 a4b53e60  r7 5e9fe8dc
    r8 66a99010  r9 5e9fef24  sl 5e9ff128  fp a4b53e60
    ip b6d4d929  sp 5e9fe818  lr a3cfe9d9  pc a3f94e26  cpsr 68030030

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00db3e26  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
ptrace attach to 26743 failed: Operation not permitted
ptrace attach to 26745 failed: Operation not permitted
ptrace attach to 26759 failed: Operation not permitted
ptrace attach to 26760 failed: Operation not permitted
"   "   "   "   "   "   "   "   "   "   "   "   "   "
<repeats all the way down>
```

All these crash reports have signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), and the same first line in the backtrace: "#00 pc 00db3e26  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so".

I'm seeing it on Android 5.0 and 5.1, across a variety of Samsung devices (Galaxy S5, Galaxy S6, Galaxy S4 Active, Galaxy Note4, etc.). All with the same address of 00db3e26.

Anyone else seeing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Facing same problem, do you have a solution?